# Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS now what

Tags: 14.04, support

I just installed Ubuntu14.04 LTS, I don’t know a bunch about computers but want to teach myself, I don’t know where to start with all the terminal, and other stuff. I've asked before and everyone answers with all this stuff about kernels and virtual boxes and a bunch of stuff I don’t understand. Newbie here, and I just want to get started on the road to actually knowing how to do stuff that is useful. Eventually want to get to programming basic games, and maybe some applications. Anything Helps, thanks.....

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?  You want to do games? do you know any programming languages? perhaps you would like to learn C/C++ and set up and IDE / compiler?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little broad; we can't just make an omni-answer that'll tell you everything to do. The best way to learn is to just use Ubuntu. Eventually, you'll find something you want to do. Once you have the idea, you can do some Googling to see if you can find an answer. If there is nothing you can find, then come here and ask a *specific question*, which we can then help with.

Find something to ask before you make a question.